# Ajax vs Redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I have an ajax based website. I am using wordpress "redirection" plugin, but instead of moving to the proper address, it only shows in the browser's address bar. When I select that and press enter or go - it is working.

Is there a way I can force the browser to select the address bar and press enter after clicking the link on my website?

Is it **window.location.replace** javascript method that I have to use? I don't really know how to use it as I am new to javascript, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`history.pushState(null, null, "Everything after / goes here");`
this js command will add a history entry and change your URL.

Comment: I bet that a plugin of wp already uses `history.pushState` because of the: `[...]but instead of moving to the proper address it only shows in a web browsers address bar. When I select that and press enter or go - it is working[...]`. My guess would be that the actual loading of the content is broken.

Comment: pushState adds the history entry and changes the URL, but does not actually _go_ to the URL, which is what the OP specifically wants ("instead of moving to the proper address it only...")

Comment: i thougth that was the problem. Then you have to change the content to the return of ajax (This is the way i do it)

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to make the user's web browser go to a new page, then you just assign to `window.location` like this:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com";
```

This will add a new history entry in the browser's back-button stack.  If you want to replace the current item in the back-button stack with the new page and have the browser go to that new place, then you can do

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

Both options will change the currently displayed page (the main difference is in the back-button stack).

---

The `history` object allows one to change the display URL without changing the page (which sounds like what the code might be doing currently), but it sounds like that is not what you want so you should switch to one of the above two options.

Comment: I see, can you tell me how to call out this in html? I have few links on one page and every each of them is redirected to a different page on external address.

Comment: @olfik - just from a regular HTML link?  If so, you don't need Javascript at all - you can just use HTML like this: `<a href="http://www.google.com">Click me</a>`.

Comment: that is the problem, using regular html link is doing what I described in first post.

Comment: @olfik - then there is javascript code in the page that is ruining/overriding the normal HTML behavior.  We can't say how to stop that override without seeing a lot more about the page (probably seeing the actual page and link).  If you tell us what the system is that makes the ajax based page work in the first place, perhaps folks can read about what that system is doing and how to avoid it for particular links.  My guess is that links can be tagged in someway so that the ajax based system will leave them alone for normal processing.